# tinyMCE plugin accessing element

Tags: javascript, plugins, tinymce

I'm trying to write a tinymce plugin, so I checked out the tutorial "Creating a plugin" on http://www.tinymce.com/. Inserting and Replacing Content is no problem, everything works fine.

Now i want to change the value of the textbox automatically after changing the value of the listbox. As an example, after changing the listbox element, the value of the active element should be written to the textbox above. How can I access this element?

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('myexample', function(editor, url)  {
// Add a button that opens a window
editor.addButton('myexample', 
{
    text: 'Example',
    onclick: function() 
    {
        // Open window
        editor.windowManager.open({
            title: 'Example Plugin',
            body: [
                // Text
                {type: 'textbox', name: 'title', label: 'Text', value: 'temp'},
                // Listbox
                {type: 'listbox', name: 'test', label: 'Ziel', 
                    'values': 
                    [
                        {text: 'Eins', value: '1'},
                        {text: 'Zwei', value: '2'}
                    ],                  
                    onselect: function(v) 
                    {
                        console.log(this.value());

                        // CHANGE THE VALUE OF THE TEXTBOX ...
                        // ????
                    }
                }
            ],
            onsubmit: function(e) 
            {
                console.log(e.data.title, e.data.test);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Now I found a solution. The best method is not to use the internal form-designer. You can use an IFrame with an external html-page, then you can work with `document.getElementById(...)`

[Here](https://github.com/cfconsultancy/tinymce4-plugin-qrcode) you can find an example

Comment: Not at all. First, tinymce windowmanager generates the ids dynamically, so ;) Second, you can have thousands of elements on one page and the id could not be unique.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I was facing the same issue and I found [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/172853/how-disable-checkbox-when-listbox-value-changes-in-tinymce) in another forum that saved my day.

The standard tinymce way to do this is to save the popup window in a variable:

```
var win = editor.windowManager.open({ //etc
```

And then for accessing the element:

```
win.find('#text'); // where text is the name specified
```

I hope this can help someone else in the future.